# What is the value of 'x' for each scenario?

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have the following C-like program, and I'm trying to figure out the final value of array x for when:

- Argument x is passed by value.
- Argument x is passed by reference.
- Argument x is passed by value-result.

**CODE:**

```
void swap(int[] list, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j] = temp;
}

void main() 
{
    int x[3] = {5, 2, 4};
    swap(x, 1, 2);
}
```

If I'm following correctly, for pass by value, in the call we have...

```
swap(x, 1, 2)
{
    temp = x[1] // temp now equals 2
    x[1] = x[2] // x[1] now equals 4
    x[2] = temp // x[2] now equals 2
}
```

...so then we have the following, correct?

```
x[3] == {5, 4, 2}
```

EDIT:

I tried compiling on ideone.com and received:

```
prog.c:1:17: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘list’
 void swap(int[] list, int i, int j)
                 ^
prog.c:8:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main() 
      ^
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:11:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘swap’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     swap(x, 1, 2);
     ^
```

Comment: The programming language only passes values by value

Comment: `int[] list` equals to `int* list` so you're always passing pointer to first element of array to this function (not value, not reference, but pointer or value of pointer if you like)

Comment: If you were passing `x` by value, `swap` wouldn't be altering the `x` in `main`, so it wouldn't do anything from main's POV. (I'm assuming some "C like" language where you can actually pass an array by value)

Comment: What do you mean by "C-like"? In actual C, the array would be effectively passed by reference here, not by value. When you pass an array like this C actually passes a pointer to the array's first member, not the array itself.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out the answer is to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you call

```
swap(x, 1, 2);
```

you are using *call-by reference*, since you are passing the argument x, which is a **pointer**
to the first element of the array x. So this swap technique will work and you will get what you are expecting, that the elements will now be in the order {5,4,2}

Comment: I see. So then what about pass by `VALUE` and `VALUE-RESULT`? Any thoughts on those?

Comment: I don't think pass by value will be useful in your scenario, since it only works on *copies* of variables rather than on the variables themselves. In any case, here is a link so that you can decide for yourself: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse505/99au/imperative/parameters.html